# Image gallery - Pinterest like layout with CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gallery

I'm working on a dynamic php gallery.
The thumbnails will all have the same width but various heights. They'll be placed from left to right. So, I don't want to use a five columns pattern.
I guess it's not possible to do it only with CSS, so maybe you know any jquery script that would do the job? I guess this kind of gallery pattern is quite common...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwdx0.png

Comment: jquery script that would do what job?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the pure css solution using css3 columns. This isn't going to work in older browsers, [read here (click).](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn) **[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/iQoLuGA/1/edit)**

You can use masonry.js, isotope.js, or packery.js for more compatible js solutions.

```
<div class="col-5">
  <div class="sm"></div>
  <div class="lg"></div>
  <div class="sm"></div>
  <div class="sm"></div>
  <div class="lg"></div>

  <div class="lg"></div>
  <div class="sm"></div>
  <div class="lg"></div>
  <div class="lg"></div>
  <div class="lg"></div>  
</div>
```

css:

```
.col-5 {
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  column-count: 5;
}

.col-5 > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sm {
  height: 75px;
}
.lg {
  height: 125px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using/jigging a Jquery plugin like the following:

http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tiles-gallery/2281417

**or**

http://codecanyon.net/item/jbmarket-image-gallery/full_screen_preview/3028128?ref=lamdang

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make the layout the 'pintrest' way, you can have an array of x columns and iterate through each column to check for the shortest height, and add the next box in that column.

That way you would know it works for all browsers [unless they have js disabled] and then you can style the width of the columns.