# Stop inline-block div contents from forcing other divs out of line.

Tags: html, css

I have some divs lined up horizontally and the content in the div is pushing it out of line with the others. How can I make them line up regardless the amount of content? I intend to add overflow:hidden so large content will not destroy the layout.  No javascript involved. Needs to work in IE9+ and chrome.

[image]

MARKUP

```
    <div class="panels">1</div>
    <div class="panels">2</div>
    <div class="panels"><img src='\images\img.png' height='64px'></div>
    <div class="panels">4</div>
```

CSS

```
.panels {
    /*line-height:200px; */
    display: inline-block;
    width:22%;
    height: 200px;
    margin:5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

I have a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/y9pEV/)**

Another saturday stolen by work. :(

Comment: If you want to get fancy on IE10+ check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130512/image-gallery-specific-layout-with-css/20131257#20131257

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you are trying to do, but, doesn't replacing display: inline-block with float: left, solves your problem?

Comment: Thanks but not really a dupe. I needed IE9+ and chrome the other post has multiple specific IDs this works on a class selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top` on `.panels`.

http://jsfiddle.net/y9pEV/2/

Comment: Doh! Of course. Thanks so much. I guess that what I get for coding mad!